# Start xterm with different shell and execute commands

Tags: zsh, xterm

My default shell environment is `bash` and I would like to start a `xterm` with `zsh` and execute some commands.

In general, to execute some commands, I am using the following

```
xterm -e "ls -lrt;pwd;whoami"
```

This is executing the commands in `bash` shell with `xterm`.

To start the `xterm` with different shell, I am using the following.

```
xterm -ls /bin/zsh
```

So, how can I combine both of these ?  When I tried. I got the below error.

```
[dinesh@mypc]$ xterm -ls /bin/zsh -e "ls"
xterm:  bad command line option "/bin/zsh"
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: To start xterm with `zsh` as the default shell, I added `SHELL=/bin/zsh` to my environment variables: `echo "SHELL=/bin/zsh" >> /etc/environment`. After that, logging out and in again should do the trick

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, the `-ls` option to `xterm` doesn't take an argument, it just specifies that the shell that `xterm` start should be a login shell.

Here's the complete section on the `-ls` flag with the part which is relevant to your issue highlighted:

```
   -ls     This option indicates that the shell that is started in the
           xterm window will be a login shell (i.e., the first character
           of argv[0] will be a dash, indicating to the shell that it
           should read the user's .login or .profile).

           The -ls flag and the loginShell resource are ignored if -e is
           also given, because xterm does not know how to make the shell
           start the given command after whatever it does when it is a
           login shell - the user's shell of choice need not be a Bourne
           shell after all.  Also, xterm -e is supposed to provide a
           consistent functionality for other applications that need to
           start text-mode programs in a window, and if loginShell were
           not ignored, the result of ~/.profile might interfere with
           that.

           If you do want the effect of -ls and -e simultaneously, you may
           get away with something like

               xterm -e /bin/bash -l -c "my command here"

           Finally, -ls is not completely ignored, because xterm -ls -e
           does write a /var/run/wtmp entry (if configured to do so),
           whereas xterm -e does not.
```

Comment: this isn't working for me `xterm -e csh -l -c 'set prompt="foo> "'`

Comment: @nmz787 No it wouldn't. It would execute the `set` command and then immediately exit since the child `csh` shell was done. You'd be better off putting that `set` command in your shell's `.login` script.

Comment: adding to the `.login` isn't a viable method for this, as I specifically need to do it dynamically and without editing a user's startup files... for now a friend simply recommended I start with a background color to differentiate shells `xterm -bg darkred csh`

Comment: This takes focus out of the current terminal window and take it back to `XQuartz`

Answer (score 11):

`xterm` uses the shell stored in `$SHELL` (variable initially set on login to your login shell) to parse the command line. So, if you want the command line to be parsed by a `zsh` shell, just do:

```
SHELL=/bin/zsh xterm -e 'echo $ZSH_VERSION; sleep 4'
```

Or you can just do:

```
xterm -e zsh -c 'echo $ZSH_VERSION; sleep 4'
```

When passed more than one argument, `xterm` won't invoke a shell to parse a command line, it will executed the first argument with its args with `execvp()` directly.

Answer (score -5):

In addition to @Stéphane's answer, you can also set your SHELL environment variable in `$HOME/.profile` with `export SHELL=/bin/zsh`, provided that you are the only person on your system who wants to use zsh.

Comment: This is not advisable if the actual shell used is not `zsh` - as it is likely to cause problems by confusing processes or subshells spawned in the shell. At best setting this variables should be set in a localised fashion (i.e. `SHELL=/bin/zsh some command`) - in every other way, it's probably best to let the shell set this value by itself.

Comment: @shalomb, no. Shells don't set `$SHELL`, `login` does. *you* would set `$SHELL` to your prefered shell (typically in `~/.profile`) to override the one set by `login` so that applications like `xterm`/`vi`, etc execute it instead of your login shell.